# Show that $M = \{(r \cos(\sigma), r \sin(\sigma), \sigma ): r \in (0,1), \sigma \in \mathbb{R}\}$is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (Helicoid)

Tags: analysis, submanifold

My tutor mentioned that i should use the regular value theorem for this. I kind of know how to do this for sets like $M=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : g(x)= 0 \}$. However i dont know how to use it on this problem because of the paramitrization form.

Comment: I think they mean you should find the g(x) yourself. Find functions which is 0 on the set M.

Comment: @Abastro do you have any buzzwords i can search for on how to do this. Dont really know how to start.

Comment: I do not know about keywords, maybe you could search for implicit function and parametrization.